# awk merging rows with the same value

Tags: bash, awk

I am working on some statistics. I have a column with hour, number idicating how many times during this hour this kind of transaction happend and the kind.

```
00 28 INFO
00 3 WARNING
01 29 INFO
01 8 WARNING
01 1 ERROR
...
```

I need to have something like that:

```
hour  INFO  WARNING  ERROR
00    28    3        0
01    29    8        1
...
```

The ERROR line is not always there, so I need some (if 3$ == "INFO" then ) in there. I know it is about arrays, but can't manage to make it work.

I would really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Show your attempt

Answer (score 1):

I can't do it in awk, but i can solve it in bash:

```
# init array with 0
declare -A matrix
for ((hour=0;hour<=23;hour++)) do
    for ((type=0;type<=2;type++)) do
        matrix[$hour,$type]=0
    done
done

# read and assign values
while read -r line 
do
    hour=$(echo $line | cut -f1 -d-)
    count=$(echo $line | cut -f2 -d-)
    type=$(echo $line | cut -f3 -d-)
    case $type in
    INFO)
        matrix[$hour,0]=$count
    WARNING)
        matrix[$hour,1]=$count
    ERROR)
        matrix[$hour,2]=$count
done < "$filename"

# output
echo "HOUR\tINFO\tWARNING\tERROR"
for ((hour=0;hour<=23;hour++)) do
    echo "${hour}\t$matrix[$hour,0]\t$matrix[$hour,1]\t$matrix[$hour,2]"
done
```

I'm nowhere near a computer. Please excuse any possible little syntax errors.